# Why Eclipse Glassfish does not support Eclipse Microprofile

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, microprofile

Why Eclipse Glassfish does not support Eclipse Microprofile ?
And I am confused about Eclipse Microprofile Application, 
Eclipse Microprofile Application can be a servlet application(war) nor ony a jar application?
I think servlet-api not nessary for Eclipse Microprofile Application.

Answer (score 3):

I'll start with your last question and work backwards.

You are correct.  The Servlet API is not part of Eclipse MicroProfile. So an implementation of the MicroProfile spec need not support servlet. If you take a look at the various MicroProfile implementations you'll see that some of them are derived from application servers, and some are not.  Those that have roots in an application server might support servlet, but others might not.

The MicroProfile spec does not specify application packaging or deployment. Just the APIs that must be supported. So some MicroProfile implementations might support war files (likely those with roots in application servers) but others won't. Most of them will support some form of an executable jar and runtime dependency management so that you can create a self-contained, immutable Docker image of your application and its runtime dependencies. In this scenario the value of war packaging is questionable.

Eclipse GlassFish is a Jakarta EE implementation, and the focus has been to deliver a Jakarta EE 8 release. MicroProfile is part of Eclipse, but it is not part of Jakarta EE (at least not yet). So there is no requirement for Eclipse GlassFish to implement MicroProfile (at least not yet).